Automatic image alignment transformations based on manually placed reference features
I am trying to trichrome film, which is the process of taking 3 different colored images, and then combining them into a final colored image. This is a relatively common practice, but I am running into one really big issue, which is that I cannot get my three images perfectly aligned, due to slight shifts in the camera, bending of the film when scanned, and other problems, my best image, looks like this:

The color blotches are my fault while developing, but the colored fringes around everything, are due to being slightly off in the alignment, because the images are slightly warped. So I need a way to warp the images back to at least the same shape. I would prefer if I could manually select points of features to align, but if there is a suitably accurate automated way to do that, it would be equally as sufficient.
